# Edit Conflict in SO Question

Tags: support, suggested-edits, specific-edit

I edited the [Rearrange rows in a table using query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946296/rearrange-rows-in-a-table-using-query) question.,  but it there now as Nick cox's Edit. This question is silly, but I want to know where I am missing.

Ref :  https://stackoverflow.com/users/839280/eager-student?tab=activity

Also if you could answer this, please let me know how you found that. i.e using some Queries etc..

Comment: What is the question here ?

Comment: Your edit was rejected by 3 people before it got edited by Nick cox. It is unknown to us (ordinary users) whether he approved or rejected your edit.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd Is a bug?

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT No, it's not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2259537) was rejected by three other users as too minor. Likely, Nick Cox had chosen to Improve your edit before the third person rejected it, meaning that even if he checked the box that your suggestion was helpful, it wouldn't have had any effect.

You can find your previous suggested edits in your [suggestions activity history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839280/eager-student?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Just click on the "suggested edit" part in front of one to view it individually.

Comment: I could not understand. Actually Nick cox edit was the same as mine. Then how could that be approved?

Comment: He has the privilege to edit without approval.

Comment: Then Morally, His edit doesnot have any effect na... (bcz both edits are same). Just for fun :)